# Are all lift-off resist negative photoresists?

Tags: nanotechnology

Are all [lift-off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-off_(microtechnology)) resist negative photoresists? I'm a bit confused as I can't find anything in my textbook/lecture slides about the type of resist used for lift-off.

Comment: In the old days there were many different positive and negative resists. That selection has dropped of late since the requirements on resists in the deep-sub-micron production world are much more stringent. But, no, I remember using positive lift-off processes in the dim dark past...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely positive photo resists, but there tends to be little incentive to use them. Usually you use a negative mask with a negative resist to create a positive part. The pattern to be made tends to be a relatively small area of the photo resist on the mask and thus it takes less time for the lithography machine to produce a negative mask which can be a bottle neck in an R&D setting. Also Positive resists tend to be perminate as they have chemically inter-reacted to stay in place not be dissolved later (like during lift-off), thus another reason positive resists are not used frequently.